# Cannot convert stdClass to String in PHP using C# web service

Tags: c#, php, web-services, object, soap

So, I know this question has been asked a lot but I'm doing as much research as I can and I can't find an answer that's worked for me yet.

I have a C# web service for a project and as a demo I'm trying to do stuff like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetResponse(string input)
{
    return "You entered " + input + ".";
}
```

And in PHP:

```
<?php
    $client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:49283/MyService.asmx?wsdl");
    $client->GetResponse("hello");
?>
```

Return value looks like this when you invoke it using the web service's home page (URL is `http://localhost:49283/BookService.asmx/GetResponse?input=hello`):

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">You entered hello.</string>
```

Doing a `var_dump` of the response looks like this:

`object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["GetResponseResult"]=> string(13) "You entered ." }`

So I know it has a string *inside* it, but I have no idea how to "extract" it out of the object. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: try `$obj->GetResponseResult`

Comment: Yes! That works. However, the only problem left is that it doesn't echo the input. I simply get "You entered ." Do you know what's causing that to happen?

Comment: try `$client->GetResponse( array('input' => "hello" ) );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to the value with `$result->GetResponseResult` test this code:

```
<?php
    $client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:49283/MyService.asmx?wsdl");
    $result = $client->GetResponse("hello");
    echo $result->GetResponseResult;
?>
```

Comment: Yes! That works. However, the only problem left is that it doesn't echo the input. I simply get "You entered ." Do you know what's causing that to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$obj->GetResponseResult` to get result from `object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["GetResponseResult"]=> string(13) "You entered ." }`

```
<?php
    $client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:49283/MyService.asmx?wsdl");
    $obj = $client->GetResponse("hello");
    echo $obj->GetResponseResult;
?>
```

---